# Conditionally add MQ broker users in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm creating AWS MQ brokers using Terraform and want to create extra users only if user name variables are set. I want to do the following which I know doesn't work but I'm looking for a way to do something similar. Any suggestions welcome.

```
resource "aws_mq_broker" "my_broker" {
  broker_name = "${var.broker_name}"
  user {
    username = "${var.broker_user}"
    password = "${var.broker_password}"
  }
  if "${var.broker_user_two}"
  user {
    username = "${var.broker_user_two}"
    password = "${var.broker_password_two}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform 0.12 will bring upgrades to the core HCL syntax to support HCL2 and, with that, [dynamic blocks](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each#dynamic-nested-blocks).

As given in the 0.12 preview guide this looks something like this:

```
# Configuration for Terraform 0.12

locals {
  standard_tags = {
    Component   = "user-service"
    Environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  # ...

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "example-asg-name"
    propagate_at_launch = false
  }

  dynamic "tag" {
    for_each = local.standard_tags

    content {
      key                 = tag.key
      value               = tag.value
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
  }
}
```

As such, you should then be able to loop through a list of users for your MQ broker with something like this:

```
variable "users" {
  default = [
    {
      username = "user1"
      password = "password1"
    },
  ]
}

resource "aws_mq_broker" "my_broker" {
  broker_name = var.broker_name
  dynamic "user" {
    for_each var.users

    content {
      username = user.username
      password = user.password
    }
  }
}
```